# What is the best way to repeat html code using javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, repeat

Using some js object like

```
links = {
    link1: "Text1",
    link2: "Text2",
    link3: "Text3"
};
```

I want to create several `<a>` elements with `href` from keys and content from values, like

```
<a href="link1">Text1</a>
<a href="link2">Text2</a>
<a href="link3">Text3</a>
```

What is the best and the shortest way to do it using js or some popular js frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use for loop in javascript.

HTML:

```
 <p id="demo" />
```

JS:

```
links = {
    link1: "Text1",
    link2: "Text2",
    link3: "Text3"
};

var element, filling = "";
for (element in links) {
    filling += "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>"
        .replace("{0}", element)
        .replace("{1}", links[element]);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = filling;
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/0subxy9m/1/

Answer (score 2):

with Angular for example and your **links** object 
HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="(link,text) in links">
    <a href="http://example.com/{{link}}">{{text}}</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.links = {
  link1: "Text1",
  link2: "Text2",
  link3: "Text3"
};
```

[**plnkr demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GlpOEEkyEITlQGx23iX0?p=preview)